# Printing numbers using getchar

Tags: c, printing, getchar

So my problem is this, I want to print a number using the `getchar` function and if I input `101` the output should be `101`, but instead I am getting `11` as the input and `0` are being ignored while they are inside the number.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define Out  0
#define In   1

void ex04();

int main() {
    ex04();
    return 0;
}

void ex04() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        int state = Out;
        if (state == Out && c != '0' && c != '\n' && c != '\t' && c != ' ') {
            state = In;
            printf("%c", c);
        } else
        if (state == In && c == '0') {
            State = In;
            printf("%d", 0);
        } else
        if (state == Out && c == '0' || c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ') {
            state = Out;
        } else
        if (state == In && c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ') {
            state = Out;
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

Input: `101`

My output: `11`

Correct output: `101`

Input: `1 2 0 4`

My output: `1 2  4`

Correct output: `1 2 0 4`

Input: `0`

My output:

Correct output: `0`

Really any help would be appreciated and btw I cannot use `scanf`.

Comment: `state == OUT` is always true, since you just assigned `state = OUT`.  So you hit the 3rd condition when you assign state = OUT and don't print anything.

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, but `state == In && c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' '` is the same as `(state == In && c == '\n') || c == '\t' || c == ' '` and probably not what you want. Why not use two nested `if` clauses, the outer for `state`, the inner for `c`?

Comment: What exactly the goal? You gave 2 input and expected output, but based on it you would be fine with `while ((c=getchar()) != '\n') if ( c >= '0' && c <= '1') printf("%c", c);`. Are there other criterias?

Comment: becasuse in the 3rd if what i want is if its inside a number and the char isnt a \n or \t or ''

Comment: theres a criteria i forgot if i type 1 2 0 4 i want 1 2 0 4 just like that as the output

Answer (score 0):

There is a precedence issue in

```
if (state == Out && c == '0' || c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ')
```

You probably mean:

```
if (state == Out && (c == '0' || c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' '))
```

The same remarks applies to the last test as well.

You should probably move the `int state = Out;` outside of the loop.

Finally I am not sure why you special case `0` in the tests, but these above fixes do change the behavior.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define Out  0
#define In   1

void ex04(void) {
    int c;
    int state = Out;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (state == Out && c != '0' && c != '\n' && c != '\t' && c != ' ') {
            state = In;
            printf("%c", c);
        } else
        if (state == In && c == '0') {
            state = In;
            printf("%d", 0);
        } else
        if (state == Out && (c == '0' || c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ')) {
            state = Out;
        } else
        if (state == In && (c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ')) {
            state = Out;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    ex04();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want that output ,just change this line `if (state == In && c == '0')` to `if (state == Out && c == '0')` ,because your `state` will be `out` after each time you go to first of loop , when you initialize something inside of a loop ,each time you traverse a loop and go to first of it,value of that variable again become initialized value. so checking `if(state==out)` is meaning less.
(in your case ,not every where)

For every character your state will be out, just delete it, using it is like `if(out==out)`
(that is reason your program  never print `0` ,because `state==out` for every character including `0`.)

look

```
#include <stdio.h>


void ex04();

int main() {
    ex04();
    return 0;
}

void ex04() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != '0' && c != '\n' && c != '\t' && c != ' ') {

            printf("%c", c);
        }
        else
            if ( c == '0') {

                printf("%d", 0);
            }
            else
                if (c == '0' || c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ') {

                    //  printf("\n");
                }
                else
                    if ( c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ') {

                        //  printf("\n");
                    }

    }
}
```

those `printf` (which I commented) will help output readability.